# How to turn a Flask Markup string into a normal string

Tags: python, flask, markup

When working with Flask, if you use [the escape function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.escape), then it will return a [Markup string](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Markup).

This Markup string will automatically turn anything added to it into escaped string.

```
#message = "Hello <em>World</em>\r\n"
message = escape(message)
#message = u'Hello &lt;em&gt;World&lt;/em&gt;!\r\n'
message = message.replace('\r\n','<br />').replace('\n','<br />')
#message = u'Hello &lt;em&gt;World&lt;/em&gt;!&lt;br /&gt;' Here <br /> is automatically escaped
#But I want message = u'Hello &lt;em&gt;World&lt;/em&gt;!<br />;'
```

The new added `<br />` is automatically escaped because the `escape()` return a Markup string.

How to turn this Markup string into a normal python string?

Comment: Are you looking for [this filter snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert to string before replacing:

```
message = escape(message)
message = str(message).replace('\r\n','<br />').replace('\n','<br />')
```

or to unicode if you have unicode symbols in message:

```
message = unicode(message).replace('\r\n','<br />').replace('\n','<br />')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters string already escaped: `message = escape(message)`

Comment: This will have error if it is a utf-8 string. I tried this method b4 I ask here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your reply. I just tried but unicode() method will not unescape it again like you said. Did you try that or read it in some docs?

Comment: @ndpu Your method works. Strangely it is not written in the official flask docs. Where did you know this method?

Comment: @JamesKing it was my assumption. Im glad that it helps

Comment: @JamesKing: ah, no, my mistake; I skipped the `escape()` step.

Comment: @JamesKing: `Markup()` is a subclass of `unicode()`; calling `unicode()` on it again simply returns the object to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `message.unescape()`?

**EDIT:** Reading your question again more carefully, I think I know understand your issue.

You need to convert your `Markup` object back into a `str` before you call its `replace` method for it to not auto-escape anymore, like so:

```
str(message).replace(foo, bar)
```

Then if you DO need to still have a `Markup` object you can convert it back.